# Reflection, generics and multiple assemblies

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I'm trying to solve this:

`Type.GetType("Class1'[[Class2]]")`

where `Class1` and `Class2` are in different assemblies.

I can parse the assemblies and find the `Class1` type as well as the `Class2` type, but how do I get to the `Class1<Class2>` type?

Comment: why are you getting the type with strings, are they internal classes in those assemblies?

Answer (score 2):

if you can find the types all you need to is:

```
Type class1Type = assembly1.GetType("Class1"); //or however you are able to get this type
Type class2Type = assembly2.GetType("Class2"); //or however you are able to get this type
Type genericType = class1Type.MakeGenericType(class2Type);
```

genericType will be like having `typeof(Class1<Class2>)`

Comment: you can mark it as the solution to your problem, that way other users can find answers without having to ask.

Comment: Was this answer not good enough to be marked as being correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think, it should look like this:

```
Type.GetType("Class1`1[Class2]");
```

Note: I changed the apostroph from ' to ` and added the number of generic arguments.

If this is not enough, try specifying the classes including namespace and assembly:

```
Type.GetType("Namespace1.Class1`1[[Namespace2.Class2, Assembly2]], Assembly1");
```

Comment: The MakeGenericType() solution is much more elegant